# BLAS routine to compute diagonal elements only of a matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, blas

Say I have two matrices `A` and `B`. I want to compute the diagonal elements of the matrix product `A * B` and place them in a pre-allocated vector `result`.

Is there a BLAS (or similar) routine to do this as fast as possible?

Comment: Some questions of that type can find the audience better at [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). It's easier to type formulas there :) While Computational Science SE does not like questions of the type: "how to implement something in C using this library", questions regarding BLAS/LAPACK are quite common.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific routine for that. However, you can use the following definition of matrix multiplication.

Consider `C = AB`, and `a`<sub>`ij`</sub>, `b`<sub>`ij`</sub>, `c`<sub>`ij`</sub> to denote the `(i,j)`th element of the corresponding matrices. Without loss of generality, I will assume that all `A`,`B`,`C` are `N` x `N` dense matrices.

Then,

`c`<sub>`ij`</sub> = sum<sub>`k=0`</sub><sup>`N-1`</sup> (`a`<sub>`ik`</sub>, `b`<sub>`kj`</sub>)

Since you are interested only in the diagonal entries:

`c`<sub>`ii`</sub> = sum<sub>`k=0`</sub><sup>`N-1`</sup> (`a`<sub>`ik`</sub>, `b`<sub>`ki`</sub>), for `i=1,...,N`

In other words, to calculate the `i`th diagonal matrix of matrix `C` you need to find a dot product between the `i`th row of matrix `A` and `i`th column of matrix `B`. That can be achieved by using a dot product BLAS level-1 function [?dot](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-dot).

`res = ?dot(n, x, incx, y, incy)`

Let's assume that matrices `A` and `B` are stored **column-wise** and are accessible via pointers `*A` and `*B` (which hold `N*N` values), while `*C` is a preallocated storage for diagonal entries of matrix `C` (which holds `N` values).

The following loop should give you the diagonal:

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    C[i] = ?dot(N,A[i],N,B[i*N],1);
}
```

Notice, that we are accessing the `i`th row of matrix `A` by passing the first element of the `i`th row: `A[i]`, and using increment (`incx`) of `N`. In contrast, to access the `i`th column of matrix `B` we pass the first element of the `i`th column: `B[i*N]` and use increment of `1`.

---

Notes:

- if `A`,`B`, and `C` have different (but consistent with matrix multiplication) dimensions, only slight modifications will have to be applied.
- if matrices are stored row-wise, the call to `?dot` should be slightly changed
- the pseudocode above uses a general `?dot` function. In practice, it will be `sdot` or `ddot` for single- or double precision real numbers, and versions of [?dotu](https://software.intel.com/en-us/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran-dotu): `cdotu` and `zdotu` for complex numbers of single and double precision, respectively.
- is it the most efficient, cache-friendly, etc-etc implementation? probably not, but it would surprise me if that becomes a bottleneck in an algorithm where `N`x`N` matrices `A` and `B` have been explicitly calculated anyway.